# Given an array in PHP where the contents are strings separated by commas, how do I extract the first part of string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file called "single.txt". The contents look like:

```
Array ( [0] => Ada Lovelace,F,96,ISTJ,Linux,24,99 
        [1] => Adele Goldberg,F,65,ENFJ,Windows,50,70 
        [2] => Alan Turing,M,41,ESTP,Mac OS X,31,50...
      )
```

First, when a new person signs up, it adds them with them with their info to the end of the .txt file. I want to be able to check whether they've already signed up and I've written the following function:

```
function returnPerson($content){
    global $person_name;

    for($i=0 ; $i < count($content); $i++){

        if($person_name == array_slice($content,0,0)){
            $person = $content[$i];
            return $person;

        } else continue;

    }

}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

How can I compare the first part of the string, i.e. the name part, to the name of the person checking?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($content)` in there, so you can see what the actual value is? Also - storing this sort of thing in a text file can be tricky; it's much better suited to be done in a database.

Comment: You should consider using a database instead of a text file. like PDO or MySQL

Comment: @andrewsi so I used var_dump and this is the following:

array(54) { [0]=> string(34) "Ada Lovelace,F,96,ISTJ,Linux,24,99" [1]=> string(38) "Adele Goldberg,F,65,ENFJ,Windows,50,70".
How would using a var_dump help me figure that part out. I realize using a db is for the best but I haven't really looked into that just yet, trying to practice some more PHP first..thanks!

Comment: @SinaSima - Isn't the third parameter for `array_slice` the number of elements you want returning? In which case, `array_slice($content,0,1)` should work.

Comment: @SinaSima - also - `var_dump` shows that you have an array of strings, not an array of arrays. So array_slice won't do anything - you'll need to add an `explode` in there, too.

Comment: @andrewsi ah, good call, thanks mate!

Comment: @SinaSima - I find `var_dump` invaluable in debugging. The number of times my variables turn out not to be what I thought they were....

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this... you may have to modify it slightly depending on how your text is coming in, but should get you on the right track :)

```
function returnPerson($content){
    global $person_name;

    foreach($content as $profile) {
        $profile = explode(',', $profile);

        if ($person_name == $profile[0]) {
            // Person Exists
            return $profile;
        }
    }

    return false; // person does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're "slicing" the same array while you're looping it. It looks like you just need a simple [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/function.strpos):

```
if(strpos($content[$i], $person . ',') === 0){
  return ...
}
```

Here's another way that doesn't require a `for` loop:

```
$names = array_map('reset', array_map('str_getcsv', $content));

if(in_array($person, $names)){
  ...
}
```

It works because your data seems to use the CSV format

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the elements in the array like this:

```
foreach ($content as $record) {
    // $record now contains string "Ada Lovelace,F,96,ISTJ,Linux,24,99"
}
```

You can extract fields from a comma-separated string by using the explode() function:

```
$string = "Ada Lovelace,F,96,ISTJ,Linux,24,99";
$fields = explode(',', $string);
// $fields[0] now contains "Ada Lovelace"
// $fields[1] now comtains "F"
// ... etc
```

Putting those together, you'll get something like:

```
foreach ($content as $record) {
    $fields = explode(',', $record);
    if ($fields[0] == $name_to_check) {
        // found it
    }
}
// didn't find it
```